# undeploy a library deployed on weblogic without affecting its dependencies

Tags: java, weblogic, wlst

I need to undeploy a library deployed on my weblogic domain but first I should undeploy all deployed applications reference to this library. this is very hard to do even in the script it will take a lot of time

do you have any way to undeploy the library without affecting any dependent application

Comment: I'm afraind this is not possible. If the goal is to deploy a newer version of the library you have to : deploy the newer version, redeploy the application and link it to the new version, and then, undeploy the older library version.

Comment: sometimes you don't have any change in your application and just have your library changed .. so you don't have to undeploy all linked application specially if you have more than 2 or three applications linked to this library

Comment: i understand, but the WebLogic Server does not allow to update a shared lib when it is used by one or several appications

Comment: really thanks for your response .. really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I found this post [WebLogic Application redeployment using shared libraries - without downtime](http://multikoop.blogspot.jp/2013/06/weblogic-application-redeployment-using.html) which may save some time than redeploying all referencing applications, though it's not the direct answer to this question.